# Merge istanbul test coverage from karma-coverage with coverage from other sources

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner, istanbul, karma-coverage, grunt-istanbul

I have several tests generating coverage reports with istanbul. One of them is generated by karma-coverage plugin. I am merging these reports with `istanbul report` but files from `karma-coverage` report are not included in the merged report.

There was an issue with file paths that had the same symptoms but it seems to have been fixed: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/pull/163

So it is probably something else.

I have tried using grunt-istanbul that instruments source files separately and then I browserify them in the bundle. I also tried using preprocessor from karma-coverage plugin to instrument the bundle. In both cases karma-coverage generates reports that look ok, but in both cases these reports are not included in the merged report.

What am I doing wrongly here? Is there some workaround maybe?

Package versions:

```
"karma": "^0.13.10",
"karma-coverage": "^0.5.2",
"grunt-istanbul": "^0.6.1"
```

karma.conf.js

```
reporters: ['coverage', 'spec'],
coverageReporter: {
  type: 'lcov',
  dir: 'coverage'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Coverage reporter should have `type: 'lcov'` - then you can merge reports

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to generate coverage separately then you can merge them as specified here:
[link](https://medium.com/@kushmisra7/one-report-for-all-test-cases-easily-merging-multiple-tests-reports-b0f5e5211a2a)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.